Change the footer by itself in the WPML menu
The menus either footer or main menu they are changing a lot,If I haven’t changed anything on HU menu. For the footer the last item is out and looks as attached image.
When I changed anything in one language other menu item changed atomatically and ruined the formate.Image related to issue
I tried to fix it but by changing the menu but its not worked and also searching a lot for the same but i didn't get exact solution.

For changing the last item on the footer, disable Auto add pages from Appearance -> Menu like the following:

If you want to have a customized footer, you can use Elementor Header & Footer Builder plugin.
